# Macbook crontab: "Service cannot load in requested session"

Tags: macos

macOS Majoave 10.14.4

My Mac is set to go to sleep after 5 minutes of no activity. I used Jiggler to prevent this. I set up a crontab that will automatically start Jiggler 8am in the morning.

0 8 * * * open -a Jiggler

It worked fine before but stopped working a few days ago. From the log I can see something like below:

com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.0): Could not import service from caller: caller = open.79537, service = com.stick.app.jiggler.13728, error = 134: Service cannot load in requested session

What could be the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because it is trying to run Jiggle with the root user, and not your MacOS user. But this app cannot run as root [and should never run as root anyway].

This message is telling this:
`com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.0`

Is says the failed session was a user domain session, for the UID 0 [which is root]

Was your MacOS user logged in at 8h00 AM on the Graphical interface? when that error occurred?

To fix it you must adjust your cron job to run under your username, and because this is a graphical application, your user need to have an active session (logged in graphically) for this job correctly be executed.

Comment: Works when I put this under my login. Thanks!